# Is it better to place promises on the front end or back end?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm currently in the process of refactoring my code since there are some load time issues that are preventing my data from being loaded properly on production.

Just to establish a better habit, would you suggest to place promises on the backend, where my db calls are being made, or on the front end where said db methods are called and the results are returned? Does using both at the same time ever happen?

Comment: When you say the db methods are called on the frontend, do you mean to say that the front end calls API endpoints that trigger the db method call on the backend?

Comment: Because it's most likely you have 2 asynchronous calls happening ... one on the frontend to call the API, and another on the backend to query the database. In this case, you can use promises in both places.

Comment: Keep in mind that using promises probably will not make your page loads faster, they are just sugar for async code

Comment: Hey @djfdev. Yeah, you're exactly right. I see. Thanks for the pointer. I've been using callbacks and they worked on my local version, but for some reason the api endpoint calls are being affected by latency i assume. I was going to rewrite everything into promises, but if you say it's just to simplify the look of the code instead of make it function better (ensuring everything is executed in the right order), I'll look deeper into my code.

Comment: Yeah I'd look elsewhere for latency issues. To edit what I said earlier, Promises are a nicer interface for async code than callbacks. async/await is actual syntactic sugar for promises.

Comment: @a_byte_of_pizza Promises simplifying your code does make it objectively better :-) And it *can* help you find bugs where things where not happening in the right order, or were unnecessarily sequential.

Comment: Front-end promises vs back-end promises would be a rather odd design choice to have to make. It is highly realistic (in a node.js app) for promises to be employed both server-side and client-side.

Comment: I see. Okay, thanks for your input guys. I apprecaite it! Thanks for clarifying some vocab as well! @djfdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as always in tech its all about trade offs, one isn't better than another however since I spend most of my time working in angular I'll tell you how I would do it:

I would write a service that takes a single value from an RXJS subscription, then unwrap it using a promise here is a firebase example:

```
  getValue(path: string): Promise<any> {
    var pathArr = path.split('/')
    var col = pathArr[0]
    var doc = pathArr[1]
    if (doc) {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.afs
          .collection(col)
          .doc(doc)
          .valueChanges()
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe((val) => {
            resolve(val);
          });
      });
    } else {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        this.afs
          .collection(col)
          .valueChanges()
          .pipe(take(1))
          .subscribe((val) => {
            resolve(val);
          });
      });
    }
  }
}
```

then I would get the value of the promise by using the .then() function, Same firebase example:

```
this.Database.getValue('Developers').then((val) => {
      var output = [];
      val.forEach((dev: any) => {
        //@ts-ignore
        output.push(dev.name);
      });
      output = output.filter((_val) => {
        return _val !== undefined;
      });
      this.options = output;
      this.filteredOptions = this.developerForm
        .get('applyTo')
        .valueChanges.pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map((value) => this._filter(value))
        );
    });
  }
```

in short my vote goes to front end haha :)

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the elaborate explanation. I too am using angular and have used firebase in the past, so this makes it a lot easier to digest. Thank you mucho!